# Timing concurrent processes in bash with 'time'

Tags: bash, time, concurrency

Is there a simple way to do the equivalent of this, but run the two processes concurrently with `bash`?

```
$ time sleep 5; sleep 8
```

`time` should report a total of 8 seconds (or the amount of time of the longest task)

Comment: To test if it takes less time to process an input file sequentially, or concurrently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ time (sleep 5 & sleep 8 & wait)

real    0m8.019s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.005s
```

Without any arguments, the shell built-in `wait` waits for all backgrounded jobs to complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
time sleep 8 & time sleep 5
```

The `&` operator causes the first command to run in the background, which practically means that the two commands will run concurrently.

Comment: Oh yes, didn't think of that third interpretion of his question. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

Using sleeps as examples.

If you want to only time the first process, then

```
time sleep 10 & sleep 20
```

If you want to time both processes, then

```
time (sleep 10 & sleep 20)
```

Comment: The second example doesn't correctly time both processes, just the second.

Comment: You're right, but regarding his newer comments, it's more or less what he asked for (his initial question wasn't clear enough).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my question may not have been exactly clear the first time around, but I think I've found an answer, thanks to some direction given here.

```
time sleep 5& time sleep 8
```

will time both processes while they run concurrently, then I'll just take the larger result.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
time parallel sleep ::: 5 8
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1